# how to add android simulator to my website?

Tags: android, angularjs, iframe, simulator

I have main site and mobile support another site. I need to added mobile simulation for main site to test mobile support site. 
If it's not clear, comment here.

Comment: If you are just testing how the main site looks in mobile - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Comment: I need to test mobile support site using main site. I asked to " how can I added mobile simulation part to main site "

Answer (score 1):

To add android simulator in your website, i suggest using
https://www.manymo.com/